# MathJS in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, mathjs

Can someone please help me how to use mathjs in ionic 2?
I just don't get it imported to use, really don't know what to do.

In ionic 1 it was easy to load the library and use it, but not so in ionic 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
npm install mathjs --save
npm install @types/mathjs --save-dev
```

in Component:

```
import * as math from 'mathjs'; // don't named as Math, this will conflict with Math in JS
```

in some method:

```
let rs = math.eval('cos(45 deg)');
```

or you could using CDN:

add this line into `index.html`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.9.1/math.min.js"></script>
```

in Component:

```
// other import ....;
declare const math: any;
```

in some method:

```
let rs = math.eval('cos(45 deg)');
```

Comment: you could do this for other 3rd party libs as well.